# How to write a custom SimpleForm Builder to replace <INPUT> by <P>?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, customization, simple-form, formbuilder

Extract of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.2.1'
gem 'simple_form', '1.4.0'
```

For any resource, I have 1 view for the 3 actions (new, edit & show). Example:

```rb
<h1><%= I18n.t('admin.form.'+action_name.downcase, :name => controller_friendly_name) %></h1>
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, resource]) do |f| %>
  <%= render "admin/shared/errors" %>
  <%= f.input :title, 
  :label => "Title", 
  :hint => I18n.t('admin.form.input.title.hint', :name => controller_friendly_name), 
  :required => true,
  :error => false,
  :input_html => { :class => :large, :placeholder => I18n.t('admin.form.input.title.placeholder', :name => controller_friendly_name) }
  %>
  <%= f.input :is_visible, 
  :as => :radio, 
  :label => "Visible", 
  :error => false, 
  :required => true, 
  :collection => [['Yes', true], ['No', false]],
  :wrapper_class => 'checkboxes-and-radiobuttons', 
  :checked => true
  %>
  <%= render "admin/shared/validation", :f => f %>
<% end %>

<% init_javascript "MyApplication.Form.disable();" if [:show].include?(action_name.to_sym) %>
```

See how the #show action set all the fields to disabled ? This is ugly.
Consider I can't refactor the views to have a show.html.erb file.

#### What I want to do:

When the action is #show, the simple_form builder use a custom builder wich replace `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` by `<p>` html tag, with the value.

Furthermore, I will customise the radiobuttons, checkboxes to.

#### My first step:

```rb
# app/inputs/showvalue_input.rb
class ShowvalueInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    # how to change 'text_field' by <p> container ?
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
  end
end
```

Can't find the way to do it. Custom Form Builders or Custom Inputs (with monkey patching) ?

Thank for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here's my solution

in my application_helper.rb:

```
    def set_show_method_to_builder(builder)
      builder.instance_eval <<-EVAL
        def show?
          #{action_name == "show"}
        end
  EVAL
    end
```

In my forms (in the simple_form block):

```
<%- set_show_method_to_builder(f) -%>
```

And finally, in #app/inputs/string_input.rb:

```
class StringInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    if @builder.show?
      content_tag(:p, @builder.object[attribute_name], :class => :show)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

There's some problem with data types not mapped, but it's another story:
[Can't create Custom inputs for some (Text, Booleans, ...) types, with SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435541/cant-create-custom-inputs-for-some-text-booleans-types-with-simpleform)